# achartengine - can't figure how to use dates as x axis - the file I save is empty

Tags: android, achartengine

I have an activity where I take the input from edit text and store it in an list.

I also store in list the current date.

Then , I press the save button which saves the above.

The next day the user enter some data more and save and so on.

I want to make a plot with x-axis date format and y axis the values the user entered.

In one activity I have:

```
...
String filename = "data.csv";    
List<Double> mydata=new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Date> mydate=new ArrayList<Date>();

....value=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_data);
...
switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.savebtn:
            savefunc();

            break;
        case R.id.graphicsbtn: 

            Intent i = new Intent();        
            i.setClassName(this,LineGraph.class.getName());                 
            this.startActivity(i);  
            break;

   public void savefunc(){

    SimpleDateFormat thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    Date d=new Date();
    try{
     d=thedate.parse(filename);
    mydate.add(d);
    }
    catch  (ParseException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    double thedata=Double.parseDouble(value.getText().toString().trim());
    mydata.add(thedata);
..
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    for (int i=0;i<mydate.size();i++){
       bw.write(mydate.get(i)+","+mydata.get(i)+"\n");
   ...
```

In the LineGraph Activity:

```
public class LineGraph extends Activity {


    private static List<Date> date = new ArrayList<Date>();
private static List<Double> data = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public Intent getIntent(Context context){

           readfunc();

      TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Showing data");
    for (int i=0;i<date.size();i++){    
        series.add(date.get(i),data.get(i));    

    }
```

The read function:

```
public void readfunc(){

    SimpleDateFormat thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    Date d=new Date();
    try{
     d=thedate.parse(filename);
    }
    catch.. 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

         do {
             s = br.readLine();     
             if (s != null ){
                 String[] splitLine = s.split(",");
                 date.add(d);//Double.parseDouble(splitLine[0]));
                 data.add(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[1]));
```

I have these problems:

1) The file I receive is empty (some problem with the Date because the method for saving and reading from a file works).

2) At the graph screen appears a white background (of course no data because the file is empty) ,but why white background?I use the same code for other purposes and I don't receive a whitebackground.

3) I am not sure how to use Dates in x axis.Should I use List ? List ? .

------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------------------------

Ok ,finally!(After user 'Dan' suggestion)

I used `ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer,"dd/MM/yyyy");`

instead of `ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer,"dd/MM/yyyy");`

and you don't need to use String List , just Date List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that deal with your file must be something like this (not compiled):

```
public void savefunc(){
    List<String> myDate = new ArrayList<String>(); //To store the formatted dates
    SimpleDateFormat thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    Date d=new Date(); //the current date
    String sd = thedate.format(d); // sd contains "16/04/2013", the formatted date
    myDate.add(sd);

    double thedata=Double.parseDouble(value.getText().toString().trim());
    mydata.add(thedata);
    ...
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    for (int i=0;i<mydate.size();i++){
       bw.write(mydate.get(i)+","+mydata.get(i)+"\n");
    }
}


public void readfunc(){

    SimpleDateFormat thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    Date d;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    do {
        s = br.readLine();     
        if (s != null ){
            String[] splitLine = s.split(","); //first substring is the formatted date
            date.add(thedate.parse(splitLine[0])); //do something with exception
            data.add(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[1]));
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: :First of all ,thanks for helping.Now, the line "date.add(thedate.parse(splitLine[0]));"doesn't work because "date" is a List<String>.Anyway , I did "Date d=new Date();
 String formattedDate=thedate.format(d);  and  date.add(formattedDate);  instead of date.add(thedate.parse(splitLine[0])); " and it works!I save the file which has 2 columns.

Comment: :Now,the only problem is the gpraph.As far as I understand in order to have dates in x-axis I must have List<Date>.So, I am trying to convert the strings we created to dates.So, I create a List<Date> Ddate = new ArrayList<Date>(); and I am trying to populate it with the dates List(from before).I do :SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date convertedDate=new Date();
try{
  for (int k=0;k<weight.size();k++){
   convertedDate = formatter.parse(date.get(k));
   Ddate.add(convertedDate);
    }but on x-axis i receive some numbers(one above the other). (i upvoted)

Comment: @George In order to have dates on the X axis, you either create a time chart or add custom labels on the X axis.

Comment: @Dan:Hello, I use "TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Showing data");
    for (int i=0;i<date.size();i++){    
        series.add(date.get(i),data.get(i));    ".Is this the time chart?Can you ponit me to some examples please?Right now,I store the dates in String List and then I try to copy them in Date List ,but instead of dates it gives me numbers (one above the other).

Comment: Your code doesn't show anywhere the type of chart you are building. ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent See this: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/ProjectStatusChart.java

Comment: @Dan:I use TimeSeries and ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent. I tried 2 things.1) Store Dates in String List and then (in Linegraph) copy these values to Date List . 2) Store Dates (Date List) and retrieve also Dates (in Linegraph).Both, result in showing big nnumbers in x axis..

Comment: @Dan:A last one please.If I want to plot a scatter graph and at the same time use the date x axis (hence,ChartFactory.getTimeChartView) ,what should I do?Because as a line graph when I enter same values the same date ,the graph overlaps.Or, can you point me to an example of adding  custom labels on the X axis you said before?Thanks!

Comment: Please ask a separate question describing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

for dynamic plots use GraphicalView rather then intent::

```
 public GraphicalView mChartView;
```

creat a xml::

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="145dip" >

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

then in ur code :

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph);
 mChartView = ChartFactory.mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, renderer)
 layout.addView(mChartView);
```

- After entering values you read from edit text fields right:
- then you are passing the new values to add in respective arraylists
- then you should call the code for linegraph again after adding new values and remember to clear series before reading arraylists (ie. `dataset.clear();`) ie. when line code function starts at beginning add dataset.clear(); because if u dont clear data will overlap and may through exception or line may look thick at old data ...

then call `mChartView.repaint();` to refresh graph

**these links too ll help u [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630898/how-to-draw-a-line-dynamically-in-android?rq=1)  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955411/dynamically-draw-lines-between-multiple-geopoints-in-android-mapview)**

Comment: :Hello , If you can help me with my example please.I don't want to do sth else now.Also , the links aren't for this kind of problem.Thanks

Comment: if u have already done for static data then mail it to me ll edit it to work for dynamic data