# Plot Time values in Y- Axis in achartengine

Tags: achartengine, timeserieschart

the timeseries has add method as add(date,double) . How to interchange it to add(double,date) ?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014103/achartengine-cant-figure-how-to-use-dates-as-x-axis-the-file-i-save-is-empt

Comment: I want to plot time on y-axis .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible the way you think but you can use if you stick to your plan to keep time on y-axis

```
mRenderer.addYTextLabel(10, "28/10/2014");
mRenderer.addYTextLabel(20, "29/10/2014");
 mRenderer.addYTextLabel(30, "30/10/2014");
```

here you will set a string as time at specific points on y.

Comment: yes , I didn't use time series now . Used the normal XYseries to plot on Y-axis. Thanks .